# Overwrite rake tasks in sinatra project and activerecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, rake

I have a Sinatra fun project and I want to improve my rake tasks so that everytime I create a new migration and migrate it I don't have to manually run them with `RACK_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate` again. Just like in Rails you run `rake db:mgirate` and the migration is run in both development and test environments. I tried overwriting the rake tasks in my Rakefile, the `migrate` task works but `rollback` does not. I've already tried everything. Appreciate your help.

```rb
namespace 'db' do
  task 'migrate' do
    Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke

    return if ENV.fetch('SINATRA_ENV') == 'production'

    # Run migration in test env as well
    ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      adapter: 'postgresql',
      database: "sinatra_project_#{ENV['RACK_ENV']}"
    )
    ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.migrate
  end

  task 'rollback' do
    Rake::Task['db:rollback'].clear
    Rake::Task['db:rollback'].invoke

    return if ENV.fetch('SINATRA_ENV') == 'production'

    # Rollback migration in test env as well
    ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      adapter: 'postgresql',
      database: "sinatra_project_#{ENV['RACK_ENV']}"
    )
    Rake::Task['db:rollback'].clear
    Rake::Task['db:rollback'].invoke
  end
end
```

Comment: The 'migrate' task is invoking the actual rails task. The 'rollback' task is just invoking itself recursively and not doing anything.

Comment: if you have to call `DatabaseTasks.migrate` to make it work then I'd assume you need to do the same for rollback https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L284

Comment: @max Wow, Max, you're so smart! You're so helpful...

Comment: @Alex Unfortunalte I get an error `NoMethodError: undefined method `migration_connection' for ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks:Module`

Comment: probably have to select the correct version you're using and see what they have in that `rollback` task